# Problem with MAX756 Boost converter

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, inductor, boost, breadboard

I'm using [MAX756](http://pdfserv.maximintegrated.com/arpdf/MAX756-MAX757.pdf) as a DC-DC boost converter to provide 3.3V from of a single 1.5 AA battery. I've implemented the circuit on page 1 of datasheet with 1N5819 instead of 1N5817 and 144uF caps between Vin and Gnd instead of 150uF. Also Vin comes from bench power supply.

I've tested three 22uH inductors with different current capabilities (all above the required 1.2A due to datasheet (page 6).
[image: schematic]
`~SHDN` and `3/~5` is connected to `out`. `LBO` is left open.
The problem is the Vout is 3.3V in no-load. But as soon as I insert the 220Ohm resistors, Vout drops and in Iout = 60mA, the Vout drops below 2V.

Here is the picture of the setup: lower rail in Vin and upper rail is Vout
[image: setup]

I've shown the other two inductors that I tested.
Anyone knows where the problem might be?
Thanks in advance.
**P.S.**
Glenn W9IQ  says:

> Take a bench supply capable of 2 amps output and set it to 7 volts.
>   Put a 4.7 ohm, 10 watt non inductive resistor in series with your
>   inductor and put this circuit across the supply. Monitor the inductor
>   voltage with your scope. You should see a nice exponential, asymptotic
>   curve that heads toward zero when power is applied. This will happen
>   within 1 us of applying power. If the beginning of the curve has a
>   different slope, your inductor is in saturation at less then 1.5 amps.
>   But your problem is more likely the ESR of your inductor and
>   capacitor. Use the right parts - it makes a difference! –

I've paralleled 5 , 2 Watts 22 Ohms resistor (so 4.4 Ohm in theory and 4.7 due to DMM).
Here is the circuit:

[image: testing L setup]
And here is the scope's result immediately after applying the power :

[image: result of testing L]

Comment: Are you really expecting people to try figure out what is connected where? and imagine where it might be behind components they cannot see through? or are you going to provide a schematic?

Comment: @PlasmaHH Sorry but I've already said that I've implemented the circuit on page 1 of datasheet. I'm adding the image ;)

Comment: Well, for one I see five capacitors on your breadboard, and only three in the schematic. Also you don't mention how you get the required 2V from a single AA battery.

Comment: "Pin 7. GND. Power Ground. Must be low impedance; solder directly to ground plane."

Comment: @PlasmaHH I didn't have 150uF cap so I've paralleled 100uF and two 22uF caps. I don't know why it is written 2V to Vout but this IC turns on at 1.2V for ~80mA load current and stays on and provides 3.3V as long as the Vin reaches 0.7V. Anyway, I've also tested Vin=2V and this problem persists

Comment: @Finbarr Yeah I know but I'm using breadboard to test it. Wouldn't using breadboard instead of PCB only result in noise in Vout and not messing with the functionality itself?

Comment: @Zeta.Investigator: Turning on doesn't mean it is designed to operate there. Having an LBO pin makes me wonder if it shuts down at 1.25V. Also these kinds of regulators often have a significantly higher startup voltage and only can go lower after they achieved good regulation.

Comment: @PlasmaHH LBO pin is low battery detection. I can alter the 1.25V limit via resistor divider. Look at page 3 the third graph from left. It says at Vin = 1.5V, Iout can be 200mA in 3.3V MODE. Also the next graph shows the start-up voltage w.r.t different loads. I mean I think I can use this IC with a single AA battery

Comment: If Iout = 60 mA and RL = 220 ohm then Vout = 13.2 volts. This doesn't tally with your detail.

Comment: @Andyaka I'm using n*220 Ohms in parallel (they are beside my breadboard) to reach 60mA

Comment: What is it you're testing, exactly? If it's to see whether the device will or won't work way out of spec with the recommended layout guidelines thrown out the window, I'd say you've succeeded.

Comment: @Finbarr I'm just testing whether I can provide 3.3V and ~50mA with a single AA battery. By guidelines you mean I can't test this device on breadboard? And other components are more or less selected with the datasheet in mind...

Comment: You may be able to, but as Glenn pointed out this particular application note shows a minimum input of 2V. And even that will assume a well laid out PCB rather than long loops of wire and push-fit connections that aren't great for handling current spikes.

Comment: (Longtime Maxim apps eng here: *this* is why we started offering Evaluation Kits, switch-mode power supplies are *very* sensitive to pcb layout and component selection. Making it work on solderless breadboard is a lost cause.)

Comment: @MarkU Thanks. Can I use it on a PCB with only two layers and no ground planes? Any specific workarounds or ideas?

Comment: MAX756 Evaluation Kit: https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/power/switching-regulators/MAX756EVKIT.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

{Added diagrams of SinglePoint VDD and SinglePoint GND}

Circuit works with no load and with 220 ohm (12mA) Iload, with 3.3 volts output.

Consider inductive bounce on the breadboard. Assume 2" of loop (in Gnd or elsewhere), or 50nH. Assume 0.1Amp in the IC's internal FET; the IC timing circuits have a minimum ON time, and thus some minimum current; we'll use 0.1amp.

Those internal FETs can be very fast, so assume 10 nanosecond to turn OFF or ON.

Result? Vbounce = L * dI/dT = 50nH * 0.1a /10nS = 0.5 volt bounce.

Nothing is well-controlled when GND or the GND rail is bouncing around with 0.5 volt.

Suggestion: build your circuit atop a sheet of copper (one-side copperclad).

Here is one physical setup that will generate this 0.5 volt upset

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWA94h.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

By the way, this is *not* the output swing, but inductive upset within (inside) the GND wiring between the IC pins. (for this example)

Comment: nice! that's some serious calculations! But I'm not seeing 0.5V Vout swing. So you are suggesting I can not actually test this IC on a breadboard? How about perfboard and solder?

Comment: If you do use perfboard and solder, make the GND a piece of braid or solderwick or copperfoil (small piece of single-sided if fine), and solder the 2 IC pins to this [bottom of cap on REF pin] , and solder the 2 big capacitors to this.

Comment: Added diagram for SinglePoint VDD, as well as SinglePoint GND.

Answer (score 4):

The app note shows that the minimum input voltage is 2 volts but you are attempting to power it with 1.5 volts.

The selection of the inductor and capacitor is quite critical to the operation. Look at page 6 for recommended suppliers and part families.

Your AA cell has an internal resistance and limited energy capacity. You should monitor the input voltage to your switcher to make sure the cell is holding up. Take note that the best efficiency for this boost converter is about 80% with proper component selection.

Building a switcher supply on a protoboard is never a good idea. With the high currents and high frequencies involved, the protoboard introduces too many strays. Dead bug / Manhattan style construction on a solid ground plane is a better approach.

Comment: I'm using bench power supply to simulate an AA. Anyway I've also tested Vin = 2V and the problem persists. All these inductors meet the required 1.2A saturation current. The IC works for no-load and 220 Ohm load but higher Iout result in failure

Comment: What are the part numbers that you used for L and C?

Comment: Seems like L does not have part number: 22uH TEM...C reads 100uF 25V FUJI

Comment: Unless you have tested these components to ensure they meet the ESR and other requirements, you can assume that this is where your problem is.

Comment: Do you know how can I test my inductor if it meets this requirement mentioned in datasheet? :`The inductors should have a saturation (incremental)
current rating equal to or greater than the peak switchcurrent limit, which is 1.2A worst-case. However, it’s
generally acceptable to bias the inductor into saturation by 20%, although this will reduce the efficiency`

Comment: Before you go there, what is the series resistance? Your cap is looks like an electrolytic when it should be a tantalum.

Comment: Datasheets wants some L with R_dc < 30 mOhms. I can't measure my R_dc with the current DMM but is read 0.1 Ohms... And the output cap is electrolyte. I don't think the caps being tantalum being a necessity. It seems it reduces the ripple

Comment: Do you have a scope?

Comment: yes I have a scope

Comment: Take a bench supply capable of 2 amps output and set it to 7 volts. Put a 4.7 ohm, 10 watt non inductive resistor in series with your inductor and put this circuit across the supply. Monitor the inductor voltage with your scope. You should see a nice exponential, asymptotic curve that heads toward zero when power is applied. This will happen within 1 us of applying power. If the beginning of the curve has a different slope, your inductor is in saturation at less then 1.5 amps. But your problem is more likely the ESR of your inductor and capacitor. Use the right parts - it makes a difference!

Comment: Thanks for the test. I updated my post with the scope's results. So can we say my inductor's sat current is over 1.5 amps?

Answer (score 1):

The output voltage on the MAX757 is set by a voltage divider between ground and the output which is connected to the feedback input (pin 2), the formula to calculate the required resistors is:

VOUT = (1.25) [(R2 + R1) / R2]

To get 5V I have used 30K for R1 and 10K for R2, for 3.3V you could use 18K for R1 and 11K for R2.

If you can find it an alternative part is the MAX756 which is a bit easier if you only need an output of 5V or 3.3V as the voltage can be set by connecting pin 2 low for 5V or high for 3.3V which negates the need for the voltage divider arrangement.

https://www.electroschematics.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/portable-5-volts-power-box.png